# htaccess two links rewriting

Tags: php

in my htaccess file I rewrite all the pages included within my main index_eng.php page into .html files.

here is the file content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index_eng.php?page=$1 [L]
# ErrorDocument 404 /404.html"
```

and it works just fine. The problem is that I want to have another page on the same folder level with index_eng.php which is going to be called index_fr.php, which will have the same pages in french and work similarly when I add the htaccess code.

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index_fr.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Only the first one is considered. The second one is neglected. Is there any workaround for this problem so that the htaccess knows both the syntaxes?

Comment: So if you receive "pageone.html", then what premise do you use to send it to index_eng.php or to index_fr.php ? to which one of those will it be sent?

Comment: The [L] flag means Last Rule. So nothing after it will match.  As Nelson states above you will need some sort of RewriteCondition to handle which one you redirect to.

Comment: NELSON: i don't know exactly what u mean ? index_eng and index_fr are two php templates which will include in their body pages from english and french floders includes. ,so it doesn't lead to anywhere it receives a parameter and shows them. that's all there is.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this..

```
RewriteEngine on
# If "lang" cookie is set, use it to get language preference
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^lang=([a-z]{2,3})[-,;]? [OR]
# else use first language in HTTP Accept-Language request header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2,3})[-,;]?
# Rewrite home page requests to script, passing language preference in query string
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=%1 [L]
```

This way you either use a user preference or look for their browser pref, and make your script smart enough to use the variable to pick the right version..

--edit--- in response to question in comment. Try something like this.

in your .htaccess include the top conditions, replace the `RewriteRule` with

```
RewriteRule  (.*)\.html$ index_%1.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Then move `index_eng.php` to `index_en.php` and you should be good (if index_eng.php is used on any direct links you can just symlink them together).

Comment: doon, i am not good at htaccess stuffs, actualyy it's just someone's code i am trying to add french part to it. and i really don't get anything from ur code (

Comment: You need someway to decide to show the user french or english. With the [L] The mod_rewrite short circuits so first match wins.  Think of it like   if (x || do_something());  If x is true, then doSomething will not be called. So in your example the request matches  (.*)\.html in the first one, so it redirects to eng. Fr will never be called.  Adding the conditions like I have in my example will redirect based on lang choice. you could probably do this RewriteRule ^$ /index_%1.php [L]

Comment: yes, i understand ,right now. but this is not matching my hirearchy.is there anyway i can keep my htacess code ,and use the [or] condition with it?

Answer (score 0):

why no use rewrite like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)_en\.html$ index_eng.php?page=$1
RewriteRule (.*)_fr\.html$ index_fr.php?page=$1
```

it is more transparent for user, to be know that right now he is on en/fr version of site; and it is easier for you to manage rewrites

Comment: pomaxa, i tried ur code but unfortunately ,isn't working for me, and it crosse my need. i don't wanna add complexity.just get the thing working :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all the reason why the second rule is neglected is beacuse you are using the `[L]` flag which stops processing the rule set. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Secondly, you want to define two rules that match the same pattern so there's no way of telling which one should go to the english index file and which should go to the french one. You should add some indicator to the rule so it knows what language to choose:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)\.html$ index_en.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.html$ index_fr.php?page=$1 [L]
```

which would match to an url like so `en/pagename.html` / `fr/pagename.html`. Or:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_en\.html$ index_en.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_fr\.html$ index_fr.php?page=$1 [L]
```

which would match to an url like so `pagename_en.html` / `pagename_fr.html`

Comment: spider , ur code isn't working with me. probably cz it's not matching my hirerchy . and i am a dummie with htaccess